# Properly ship a database driver in a war

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

Tomcat7 [added](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#DriverManager,_the_service_provider_mechanism_and_memory_leaks) functionality to prevent memory leaks and now recommends putting database drivers in $CATALINA_BASE/lib.

How would I load this without putting it in the shared folder? Is it possible to manually register the database driver in a context listener and unloading it on shutdown, if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can put DB JARs in myapp/WEB-INF/lib. As you say, you can use a ServletContextListener implementation to call java.sql.DriverManager.deregisterDriver(Driver driver) as the application unloads.